# Attaching a HTML anchor link to a Dropdown in a Nav menu bar

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn"><a href="#Control-Center"> Control Center</a>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href = "">Trend</a>
                        <a href = "">Intel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have a section on my webpage called Control center and I want to make it so that when someone clicks on the Nav Bar, it takes them to that section of the page. I made the Drop down of the Nav Bar on hover so that when they click on the nav bar it would take them to different sections within the page.
When I add `<a href="#Control-Center">` part to this the nav bar gets all buggy. I tried changing the heiarchy like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#Control-Center"><button class="dropbtn">Control Center</button></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href = "">Trend</a>
                        <a href = "">Intel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but it still does not look good. There is functionality but the dropdown goes haywire.

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Thank You

Comment: you don't need to add button in a tag you can give class="dropbtn" to the button. Please share your css so we can see the problem it's difficult to understand like this

Comment: please also check are you giving id correctly to your section maybe you are giving id like this id="#Control-Center" so that' why its creating an issue or missing some tag in your code

Comment: Yes I am giving id="#Control-Center", if not this then how should I give it? I am inserting my id as such: <h2 id="Control-Center">Control Center</h2>

Comment: <h2 id="Control-Center"> you don't need to add # with id attribute just give a name and html will understand it's an id.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue a week ago when using this web template:
[W3 school template](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_architect.htm).

It wouldn't jump in the normal sense (out of that Top Nagivation bar).
But it WOULD jump there when I duplicated that JumpTo link on the main page near the top (and hidden it in a closed JS script), then when I click on the top navigation bar button it does jump down to the very bottom of the page where I want it to land.
See below how we did it.

TOP NAV:

```
<a href="#JumpTo" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Projects</a>
```

Somewhere near top of page but hidden:

```
<!--<a href="#JumpTo" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">&nbsp;</a>-->
```

Destination at bottom of page in footer (where I tested it).

```
<footer id="JumpTo" class="w3-center w3-black w3-padding-16">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, not precisely what you're looking for, but maybe try an HTML details element?

```html
<details>
<a href="https://ronnieroyston.com">link1</a><br>
<a href="https://ronnieroyston.com">link2</a><br>
<a href="https://ronnieroyston.com">link3</a>
</details>
```